# Как закинуть файлы на сервер с помощью linux

Tags: linux

Имеется следующая проблема: есть заархивированная папка в которой лежит блокнот со скриптом и ещё один файл в формате json, все это дело мне надо закинуть на сервер. Собственно есть идея просто создать файлы на сервере с командой nano и так туда все скопировать и вставить. И второй вариант по которому самый главный вопрос можно ли как то взять этот один архивированный файл и с винды все это закинуть через терминал на сервер? С linux опыта нет, задача вроде не сложная, собственно поэтому и спрашиваю, помогите пожалуйста :)

Comment: полагаю нужно дествовать через ftp сначала закинуть ну и если есть удаленная консоль то можно и разархивировать потом

Answer (score 6):

Если с Винды - winscp - программа для передачи файлов по ssh.

Если вы сидите под Linux - в файловом менеджере нажмите <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> и введите `sftp://user@host/`

Comment: Либо через FileZilla Client, там тоже встроена поддержка SFTP

Answer (score 0):

Можно и с помощью putty.
Сначала коннектитесь к удаленной машине через putty, для того чтобы обменяться ключами.
А затем выполняете команду:

```
pscp C:\tmp\youtLocalFile.txt user@host:~/remode_dir
```